# Unable to access Image files in CSS "background: url(image_path)" attribute in a Spring MVC Application

Tags: css, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application from which I am trying to access images in a CSS file's `background: url(image_path)` attribute.

The CSS works perfectly fine, but the image is not getting displayed. I think there is a problem with addressing the image file.

I tried absolute addressing as well as relative-addressing to get the image, but it doesn't work.

`background-image: url("resources/images/forIndex/bg1.jpg");`

I also tried:

`background-image: url("../images/forIndex/bg1.jpg");`

My **webapp package** is as follows:

[image]

**style.css:**

```
#home {
 background:
    url(../images/forIndex/bg1.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 height: auto;
 min-height: 710px;
 padding-top: 60px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#overview-video {
 background: url(resources/images/forIndex/bg2.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: scroll;
 text-align: center;
}
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml 
    /WEB-INF/spring-security-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Mapping for images -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Somebody, Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need servlet mapping for the images in web.xml, as it will go through the dispatcher servlet.

Otherwise the config seem Ok. On some url like **www.mysite.com/index.html** you should be able to access the images like this:

```
background-image: url("resources/images/forIndex/bg1.jpg")
```